# How to protect a folder in iOS app file system?

Tags: ios, security, filesystems

A colleague told me that Google's gmail iOS app used to have a protected folder a while ago. By "protected" means when he tried to **browse into** that folder by using iFunBox, he couldn't do it. Although, he wasn't able to demonstrate this to me, I was intrigued by this subject.

So, I researched; the only thing I found so far is the `NSFileProtectionKey`. It let you prevent a file from being read when device is locked. However, I didn't come across a way to protect folder.

Is there a way to protect folders in iOS app?

Comment: protect a folder from *what*?  having the contents examined or simply listed?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann simply listed

Comment: afaik, there's no API that does what you are asking for.  In general, most users never look through their iPhone's file system (nor know how to; you just happen to be able to do it via iFunBox).  If you make a folder's contents unlistable, then how would any NSFileManager call, or any other path/file-URL-parsing method, know how to succeed?  My guess is that the gmail app had an encrypted *file* in which they kept a virtual file system, or list of files/data/messages that only the gmail app knows how to work with.  This may be the approach you need to take with your own app.